# How to convert incomplete time series into a complete time series (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have some time series data that is not complete (timestamps are at random intervals). How can I turn the data into data with fixed intervals without changing the key timestamps?

Here is a small sample of the time series data that is being talked about:

```
Date/Time,Cmltv Net Profit
2013-05-28 00:00:00,-14000.0
2013-05-30 00:00:00,-14000.0
2013-05-30 00:00:00,-24200.0
2013-06-07 00:00:00,-38200.0
2013-06-07 00:00:00,-11200.0
2013-06-24 00:00:00,-49400.0
2013-06-24 00:00:00,-13800.0
```

Any insight will be helpful. I haven't tried anything simply because I have no clue where to even look for a solution.

Comment: Why do you have multiple same Date/Time? And mainly why the spread between values are so large for a same Date/Time?

Answer (score 0):

If need unique values of `Date/Time` is possible use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `sum` for aggregate duplicated datetimes:

```
df1 = df.resample('D', on='Date/Time').sum().reset_index()
print (df1)
    Date/Time  Cmltv Net Profit
0  2013-05-28          -14000.0
1  2013-05-29               0.0
2  2013-05-30          -38200.0
3  2013-05-31               0.0
4  2013-06-01               0.0
5  2013-06-02               0.0
6  2013-06-03               0.0
7  2013-06-04               0.0
8  2013-06-05               0.0
9  2013-06-06               0.0
10 2013-06-07          -49400.0
11 2013-06-08               0.0
12 2013-06-09               0.0
13 2013-06-10               0.0
14 2013-06-11               0.0
15 2013-06-12               0.0
16 2013-06-13               0.0
17 2013-06-14               0.0
18 2013-06-15               0.0
19 2013-06-16               0.0
20 2013-06-17               0.0
21 2013-06-18               0.0
22 2013-06-19               0.0
23 2013-06-20               0.0
24 2013-06-21               0.0
25 2013-06-22               0.0
26 2013-06-23               0.0
27 2013-06-24          -63200.0
```

If need avoid aggregation duplicates datetimes use left join with helper `DataFrame`:

```
df22 = pd.DataFrame({'Date/Time' : pd.date_range(df['Date/Time'].min(),
                                                 df['Date/Time'].max())})
df2 = df22.merge(df, how='left')
```

---

```
print (df2)

    Date/Time  Cmltv Net Profit
0  2013-05-28          -14000.0
1  2013-05-29               NaN
2  2013-05-30          -14000.0
3  2013-05-30          -24200.0
4  2013-05-31               NaN
5  2013-06-01               NaN
6  2013-06-02               NaN
7  2013-06-03               NaN
8  2013-06-04               NaN
9  2013-06-05               NaN
10 2013-06-06               NaN
11 2013-06-07          -38200.0
12 2013-06-07          -11200.0
13 2013-06-08               NaN
14 2013-06-09               NaN
15 2013-06-10               NaN
16 2013-06-11               NaN
17 2013-06-12               NaN
18 2013-06-13               NaN
19 2013-06-14               NaN
20 2013-06-15               NaN
21 2013-06-16               NaN
22 2013-06-17               NaN
23 2013-06-18               NaN
24 2013-06-19               NaN
25 2013-06-20               NaN
26 2013-06-21               NaN
27 2013-06-22               NaN
28 2013-06-23               NaN
29 2013-06-24          -49400.0
30 2013-06-24          -13800.0
```